# Process send_link doesn't work when the parent process dies, even after unlinking

Tags: erlang, elixir

I have

```
Process.send_after(self(), {:do_thing, type, x, z, 0}, 60_000)
```

Then if the parent process dies that never happens
So I tried

```
      {:ok, pid} =
        Task.start_link(fn ->
          Process.send_after(self(), {:do_thing, type, x, z, 0}, 60_000)
        end)
      Process.unlink(pid)
```

but that still didn't fix it. what do I do.

I also tried

`this = self()` and then `Process.send_after(this, {:do_thing, type, x, z, 0}, 60_000)` and it didn't work.

Comment: It seems like the current process gets killed when the parent process dies - and because the `send_after` is aimed at `self()`, there no longer is a process to send the message to. If you need `do_thing` to happen independently of these two processes stopping, it might be simpler to add a third process that has `do_thing` as its responsibility.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the Process module [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Process.html#send_after/4):

> The timer will be automatically canceled if the given dest is a PID
> which is not alive or when the given PID exits.

An example can be made to work if the `dest` process is still alive when the timer goes off.  Below is an example that shows a Dog process spawning a Cat process, then the Cat process calls `Process.send_after/3`, which sends a message back to a third process. Both the Dog and Cat process no longer exist when the timer goes off.

```
defmodule Start do
  def spawn_dog do
    spawn(Dog, :bark, [ self() ])

    receive do
      msg -> IO.puts("Start process got message: #{msg}")
    end

  end
end

defmodule Dog do
  def bark(start_pid) do
    IO.puts("Dog process says bark.")
    spawn(Cat, :meow, [start_pid])

    IO.puts("Dog process exiting.")
  end

end

defmodule Cat do
  def meow(target_pid) do
    IO.puts("Cat process says meow.")
    Process.send_after(target_pid, "Cat wants food.", 3000) #Dog process above will exit
                                                            #before timer goes off.
    IO.puts("Cat process exiting.")  #Cat process will exit before timer goes off.
  end
end
```

In iex:

```
iex(21)> c("start.ex")    
warning: redefining module Start (current version defined in memory)
  start.ex:1

warning: redefining module Dog (current version defined in memory)
  start.ex:12

warning: redefining module Cat (current version defined in memory)
  start.ex:22

[Cat, Dog, Start]

iex(22)> Start.spawn_dog()
Dog process says bark.
Dog process exiting.
Cat process says meow.
Cat process exiting.
Start process got message: Cat wants food.
:ok
```